# How to convert an object to String using Gson

Tags: android, gson

I've been using Gson (version 2.6.2) for like almost two years now. But from last few days I am getting this below error while I am trying to convert an object to a String.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible
```

I have this class:

```
public class VisitReportModel implements SyncableEntity
{
    private final String LOG_TAG=VisitReportModel.class.getSimpleName();

    private Long Id;
    private Date VisitDate;
    private Date NextVisitDate;
    private String AdvisorId;
    private String ProducerId;
    private Date LastUpdate;
    private List<FieldModel> Fields;
    private Long CropTypeId;
    private String Observations;
    private Boolean Deleted;
    private Integer Year;

    // Local id for searching after upload and set the id received
    private Long LocalId;

    public VisitReportModel()
    {
    }

    public VisitReportModel(VisitReportModel visitReport)
    {
        List<FieldModel> fieldModels = visitReport.getFieldModels();
        Fields = fieldModels;

        setId(visitReport.getId());
        setDeleted(visitReport.getDeleted());
        setVisitDate(visitReport.getVisitDate());
        setNextVisitDate(visitReport.getNextVisitDate());
        setAdvisorId(visitReport.getAdvisorId());
        setProducerId(visitReport.getProducerId());
        setLastUpdate(visitReport.getLastUpdate());
        setLocalId(visitReport.getLocalId());
        setCropTypeId(visitReport.getCropTypeId());
        setObservations(visitReport.getObservations());
        setYear(visitReport.getYear());
    }
}
```

(I excluded all getters and setters).

The error occurs when I'm trying to convert this VisitReportModel object to String (specifically in the second line):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonObjectInString = gson.toJson(visitReport);
```

But the weird is that I've been doing this for a long time and now this error happened and I really don't know why. Anybody has a clue or something? Thanks!

Comment: is this happens on only `Android M`

Comment: Yes, it's happening in Android M and after api's. In api's before the app get's stuck at the line without throwing the error.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, searching through the web I realized that I had to add the @Expose annotation to all fields that I wanted to be serialized/deserialized. So my object ended like this:

```
public class VisitReportModel implements SyncableEntity
{
    private final String LOG_TAG=VisitReportModel.class.getSimpleName();
    @Expose
    private Long Id;
    @Expose
    private Date VisitDate;
    @Expose
    private Date NextVisitDate;
    @Expose
    private String AdvisorId;
    @Expose
    private String ProducerId;
    @Expose
    private Date LastUpdate;
    @Expose
    private List<FieldModel> Fields;
    @Expose
    private Long CropTypeId;
    @Expose
    private String Observations;
    @Expose
    private Boolean Deleted;
    @Expose
    private Integer Year;

    // Local id for searching after upload and set the id received
    @Expose
    private Long LocalId;
    ....
```

After this I added to my GsonBuilder the excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation() so only the fields with the @Expose annotation are going to be serialized or deserialized:

```
    new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonDefaultTimeZoneAdapter())
            .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC)
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this error occur, I am still searching. But I found one solution that worked for me.

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC);
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Hope it works!!!

Comment: I saw this kind of solution on some other sites but it's not working for me. Thanks anyway Heisen-Berg

Comment: Google have to do something to fix it.

Comment: But how this error happened to you? In my case I just modified other classes but not the ones related to Gson conversion and the problems started to appear

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled proguard in your app then try serializing / deserializing this way:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class VisitReportModel implements SyncableEntity
{
    private final String LOG_TAG=VisitReportModel.class.getSimpleName();

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Long Id;

    //............
}
```